# Looking for a continuous, unit-norm vector field

Tags: continuity, vector-fields

I want to find a 2D vector field with three characteristics:

1. it is continuous
2. all the vectors are unit length
3. vectors on the unit circle point to the origin

Is this possible?  I haven't been able to find an example, and I'm beginning to think that something analogous to the hairy ball theorem applies.  Is it possible if one of the constraints is loosened, such as allowing the norm to vary in a range of positive values?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. A unit vector field defines a map to $S^1$; your assumption that all the vectors on the unit circle point towards the origin says that this map is the antipodal map $f: S^1 \to S^1$, $x \mapsto -x$. If you could extend this over the disc $D^2$, that would define a [null-homotopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy#Null-homotopy) of your map $S^1 \to S^1$. (If you write points in $D^2$ radially, i.e. as $(r,\theta)$, and we call your extension $v: D^2 \to S^1$, the null-homotopy is defined by $f_t: S^1 \times I \to S^1$, $f_t(\theta) = v(t,\theta)$; automatically $f_1$ is a constant map.)

However, your antipodal map represents a generator of $\pi_1(S^1) \cong \Bbb Z$, the [fundamental group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_group) of $S^1$, and it is not null-homotopic.

Comment: Everything I'm saying here can be phrased in terms of the [winding number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number), if you so desire.